# Messed up custom ListView made in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I am fetching some data from an API and populating it in a list view but when data populates list view is messed up.

Code of my listview_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="BTC/AUD"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="LTC/BTC"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTimeBtcToAud"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvVolBtcToAud"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Vol"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPriceBtcToAud"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTimeLtcToBtc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvVolLtcToBtc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Vol"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPriceLtcToBtc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    autofit:minTextSize="6sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When i open up design tab in Android Studio i see this which is exactly what i want:
[image: Custom layout for list view]

Code of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.byteshaft.tradealerterbtcm.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/ll_all_data">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_all_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:divider="@null">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And code of my MainActivity in which i am fetching and populating data into a list view:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView lvAllData;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;

    ArrayList<Integer> ListIds;
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> hashMapList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lvAllData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_all_data);
        getBtcToAud();
    }

    private void getBtcToAud() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(MainActivity.this);
        request.setOnReadyStateChangeListener(new HttpRequest.OnReadyStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyStateChange(HttpRequest request, int readyState) {
                switch (readyState) {
                    case HttpRequest.STATE_DONE:
                        switch (request.getStatus()) {
                            case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                                onDataFetchSuccess(request.getResponseText());
                                break;
                            default:
                                onDataFetchFailed(request.getResponseText());
                                break;
                        }
                }
            }
        });
        request.setOnErrorListener(new HttpRequest.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(HttpRequest request, int readyState, short error, Exception exception) {}
        });
        request.open("GET", "https://api.btcmarkets.net/market/BTC/AUD/trades");
        request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        request.send();
    }

    private void onDataFetchSuccess(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data fetch successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("data", "" + response);
        ListIds = new ArrayList<>();
        hashMapList = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                int id = jsonObject.getInt("tid");
                Log.e("object", "" + jsonObject);
                if (!ListIds.contains(id)) {
                    ListIds.add(id);
                    ArrayList<String> tempArrayListData = new ArrayList<>();
                    tempArrayListData.add(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                    tempArrayListData.add(jsonObject.getString("amount"));
                    tempArrayListData.add(jsonObject.getString("price"));
                    hashMapList.put(id, tempArrayListData);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_row,
                ListIds);
        lvAllData.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    private void onDataFetchFailed(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data fetch failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("failed", "" + response);
    }

    private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        ArrayList<Integer> arrayListIds;

        ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Integer> ids) {
            super(context, resource);
            arrayListIds = ids;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);

                viewHolder.tvTimeBtcToAud = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeBtcToAud);
                viewHolder.tvVolBtcToAud = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVolBtcToAud);
                viewHolder.tvPriceBtcToAud = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPriceBtcToAud);
                AutofitHelper.create(viewHolder.tvTimeBtcToAud);
                AutofitHelper.create(viewHolder.tvVolBtcToAud);
                AutofitHelper.create(viewHolder.tvPriceBtcToAud);

//                viewHolder.tvTimeLtcToBtc = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeLtcToBtc);
//                viewHolder.tvVolLtcToBtc = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVolLtcToBtc);
//                viewHolder.tvPriceLtcToBtc = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPriceLtcToBtc);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.tvTimeBtcToAud.setText(hashMapList.get(arrayListIds.get(position)).get(0));
            viewHolder.tvVolBtcToAud.setText(hashMapList.get(arrayListIds.get(position)).get(1));
            viewHolder.tvPriceBtcToAud.setText(hashMapList.get(arrayListIds.get(position)).get(2));

//            viewHolder.tvTimeLtcToBtc.setText();
//            viewHolder.tvVolLtcToBtc.setText();
//            viewHolder.tvPriceLtcToBtc.setText();
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayListIds.size();
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        AutofitTextView tvTimeBtcToAud;
        AutofitTextView tvVolBtcToAud;
        AutofitTextView tvPriceBtcToAud;
        AutofitTextView tvTimeLtcToBtc;
        AutofitTextView tvVolLtcToBtc;
        AutofitTextView tvPriceLtcToBtc;
    }
```

And when data populates it looks like this :D
[image: Messed Up data]

I want my layout is to look like the following image:

[image: Actual]

I know that i am doing something terribly wrong but i can't figure it out.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In your code heading of the list items define in the listview_row.xml file. Instead of that move you headings code to the activity_main.xml. Add only list item details in the listview_row.xml file.

In your code you are populating heading and data for each row. once you moved headings part main xml file.

// Add **id** this in listview_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="BTC/AUD"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="LTC/BTC"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Later read this id in ViewHolder class
TextView listHeading;

Now try to comment this heading if position is >0 as following:

```
     if(position==0){
 viewHolder.listHeading.setText(hashMapList.get(arrayListIds.get(position)).get(0));
}
```

Make divider height 0 in the for ListView in the xml.

Finally, you need do these kind of changes for **Time,Vol and price** heading

Comment: Any suggestions how would i do that?

Comment: Check the updated answer above you may get idea. You don't need to move any code as said previous. You just need to modify those changes.